# Compile-time error on declaration of `errno`

Tags: c++, linux

During the process of compilation of my C++ program on Linux, it gives the following warning:

```
warning #584: omission of exception specification is incompatible with previous function "__errno_location" (declared at line 43 of "/usr/include/bits/errno.h")
extern int errno;//error handling
         ^
```

The code is shown below:

```
#include <errno.h>    //for error handling
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

extern int errno;//error handling
```

`errno` is a global variables, it is used in other `.cpp` files.  How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you declaring `errno` when it's already declared in `errno.h`?

Comment: More to the point: `errno.h` already declares `errno`, so *don't* try to declare it yourself.

Comment: On today's systems `errno` *cannot* be an ordinary scalar variable to be multi-thread compatible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`errno` is required to be a "modifiable lvalue", not necessarily a declared object.

Apparently on your implementation, `errno` expands to an expression that includes a call to a function called `__errno_location`.

In your own declaration:

```
extern int errno;
```

`errno` expands to that expression, resulting in an error.

Since `<errno.h>` *already* declared `errno` for you, there's no need to declare it yourself, and as you've seen, you *can't* declare it yourself.

Just omit that `extern` declaration.